# Write math in two columns in a page

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, two-column

Is there any simple way to split my page in two without using a multi column document to achieve this result:

[image]

What I currently have is this:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
T\left(n\right)&= 2T(n/2)+(c_2 + c_3)\cdot n + c_1 c_4 \\
T\left(n\right)&= 2T(n/2)+c'\cdot n + c'' \\
T\left(n\right)&= 
\begin{cases}
c &\text{if } n<2 \\
2T(n/2)+c'\cdot n& \text{if } n \geq 2\\
\end{cases}\\
T\left(n\right)&= 2(2T(n/4)+c'\cdot \frac{n}{2})+c'\cdot n\\
               &= 4T(n/4)+2c'n\\
               &= 8T(n/8)+3c'n\\
               &\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\vdots}} \\
               &= 2^k T(n/2^k)+kc'n\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You need the vertical rule? And you want the left/right side to be aligned at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the each of the blocks inside a `minipage` that is just wide enough to fit 50% of the text block minus half the width of the rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum,calc}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-.2pt}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{align*}
      T(n) &= 2T(n/2) + (c_2 + c_3) \cdot n + c_1 c_4 \\
      T(n) &= 2T(n/2) + c' \cdot n + c'' \\
      T(n) &= \begin{cases}
        c & \text{if $n < 2$} \\
        2T(n/2) + c' \cdot n & \text{if $n \geq 2$} \\
      \end{cases} \\
      T(n) &= 2(2T(n/4) + c' \cdot \frac{n}{2}) + c' \cdot n \\
           &= 4T(n/4) + 2c'n \\
           &= 8T(n/8) + 3c'n \\
           &\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\vdots}} \\
           &= 2^k T(n/2^k) + kc'n
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}%
  \vrule
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-.2pt}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{align*}
      T(n) &= 2(2T(n/4) + c' \cdot \frac{n}{2}) + c' \cdot n \\
           &= 4T(n/4) + 2c'n \\
           &= 8T(n/8) + 3c'n \\
           &\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\vdots}} \\
           &= 2^k T(n/2^k) + kc'n
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
}

\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The `\vrule` inside a horizontal box (`\makebox[\linewidth]`) stretches to fill the entire box vertically, thereby making it seem like the set constructions are separated by a vertical rule. The `minipage`s are aligned at the `[t]`op.